# Python append/concatenate numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, concatenation

I have develop a code to read all the specific file and save as numpy format such as

```
     [[1 2]
      [3 4]
      [5 6]]
```

But in my code, the numpy array return empty, can anyone help me to solve it? Thanks.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np
list1=np.array([])
for x in range(101563,103807):
try:
    x=str(x)
    X=open("auto"+x)
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)
    X=X_train_counts.shape
    X=np.array([[X[0],X[1]]])
    list1=np.append(list1,X, axis=0)
except:
    y=x
```

Comment: So your files don't have extensions?

Comment: no…what kind of extension do you refer?

Comment: `.txt` or `.csv` or something?

Comment: no, my file don't have any extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to accumulate values in a list:

```
alist = []
for ... in range:
   ....
   alist.append(new_array)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

You are already doing that in the `X=np.array([[X[0],X[1]]])` line - giving `array` a list of lists.

`np.append` is hard to use correctly.  `np.array([])` is not the right starting point.  It's slow, since it's building a new array each time.  On the plus side you are using the axis parameter, and aren't trying use it in-line.

Do use an open ended `try/except`.  It hides coding errors.  You probably get the original `list1` because the `append` throws an error, and nothing gets executed in the loop.